# Resizing viewport produces unwanted space between fixed divs positioned in line (not css inline)

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to avoid the space from appearing at any window width while maintaining the left elements width in percent and the right elements `transform: translate` of the same value.

The code. Or see here https://jsfiddle.net/s53tLqo6/

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>

.left, .right {
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
}

.left {
    width: 80%;
    left: 0;
    background: #500;
}

.right {
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    background: #005;
    transform: translate(80%);
}
```

If I drag the side of the view-port a gap will keep appearing and disappearing at different resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not confident what the precise issue is, but my assumption is subpixel widths. If you look at the width of the `left` `div`, the white gap usually appears when there is a pixel value of `.49px` or below (eg: `1034.19px`) but is fine if the pixel value is `.5px` or above.

I would suggest trying to use CSS grid, it appears to also resolve this issue:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
}

.left,
.right {
  height: 100px;
}

.left {
  background: #500;
}

.right {
  background: #005;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally advise using flex as this results in more consistent results.
The elements are positioned from left to right in the order that they appear in the container; so your left element is first, and then your right element. All the `.left and .right` classes are doing in colouring the divs and setting how wide you would like them.

**Example:**

```css
.left {
  width: 80%;
  background: #500;
}

.right {
  width: 20%;
  background: #005;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```